# repeating processes and then making changes in MS projects

Tags: ms-project

IN excell "=" duplicates the original cell ( does not copy once off) so if the original cell changes the duplicate cell also changes. How do I do the same when I repeat a process a multiple times in MS projects ( i.e. I have a 10 step process for licensing which I repeat 20 times. If I want to make a change in one of the steps in the original process I don't want to correct the copy/past 20 times.

Any ideas ?

Comment: At first blush, that seems too low level to schedule in a project schedule. Do you have different charge codes for each process step? For each process, is the subsequent process dependent on the predecessor process to finish? Or do they or can they occur simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to create a recurring task in Microsoft Project:

1. Select Insert – Recurring Task from the drop-down menu.
2. The dialog box for Recurring Task Information displays.
3. Fill in the task's name, duration, recurrence pattern, and start date, as well as any applicable calendars.
4. Click the OK button.

---

---

---

If you need to modify information for several Tasks in MS PROJECT

1. First, you'll establish a simple Project
2. If you want to edit all of them (or some of them), you must first choose the Tasks and then click information (on the RHS of your screen)
3. and you'll receive
   [image]
4. you'll go over all of the tabs, but not all of the fields; instead, you'll focus on the most important.

**Tab "General"**

Name: If you type something in this field (for example, Development), it will be applied to all selected Tasks.

Duration: If you enter a value in this field, the duration of all selected tasks will be the same.
Percent complete: If you enter a number, all tasks will have the same percentage.

Schedule Mode: Manually or Auto Schedule Mode will be selected for all Selected Tasks.

**Advanced Tab**

Deadline: For all Selected Tasks, you can choose the same Deadline date.

Constraint Type: For all Selected Tasks, you can select a constraint type (for example: SNET, ASAP, FNET, ALAP, etc.) and enter the relevant date.

Task type: You can select Fixed Units, Fixed Work, or Fixed Duration, as well as whether or not Tasks are Effort or Non-Effort driven (Fixed Work type is always effort driven)

As you can see, predecessors are not allowed for Multiple Tasks, which makes sense!

You can find more about MS Project here: http://www.tacticalprojectmanagement.com/tutorials/microsoft-project-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a recurring task, so much as a repeated application of a standard sub-process.  It sound like you wish to change the wording or other details of the master definition of this workpackage, and have it propagate to other instances where it is used in the project.

As far as I know, MSP doesn't support this idea of object-propagation.  It has the concepts of tasks, resources and calendars, but not *blocks of stuff* or *pointers*.

You are either going to have omit these low-level details from the plan, do lots of copy pasting (~20 times, that's not so bad!!), or consider round-tripping via Excel (where you can use formulae to propagate changes to multiple places).